# Writing two different language scripts on the same page

Tags: html, internationalization

I have (I think all Serbians have) an issue regarding indexing pages by google bot: it treats Latin and Cyrillic scrips as they are different and thus making different rankings and so on. But they are just two scripts that represent the same thing. In our language written "problem" and "проблем" have both the same meaning, they are also pronounced the same and they are written with the same rules applied to the sentence.

Recently I had to change my website script from Cyrillic to Latin because people here are using Latin more than Cyrillic (in mobiles and computers). But I am reluctant to do it, so I am thinking what else I can do to make Cyrillic script still on my page?

So finally I've decided to write both Latin and Cyrillic script on my pages. Latin script will be visible and Ciryllic will be in hidden collapsible section (or div). But how to denote that that section is actually holding Cyrillic script? If I use lang="sr-Cyrl" do I have to use it on all nested elements as well?

Thanks

Comment: The `lang` attribute cascades, you should set it on the topmost element that contains only that language. If you’re mixing languages throughout the site, you should set the “main” language on the top HTML element and individually tag differing sections throughout the page with different languages. But really, it would seem sensible to have a language switch which allows you to present two separate pages with separate URLs, e.g. `/foo` and `/cyrl/foo`, or `/foo?l=cyrl` or something along those lines.

Comment: @deceze thanks! I was thinking about this a lot and realized that these are not languages but scripts and they can be transliterated online without any loss of characters or meaning (with the simple letter swapping). But because Google is (miss)treating those two scripts, I will put it in the same page and see how google will handle it then.

Comment: Well, they’re different *locales*, whether they say the same thing or not. I could at least *read* the Latin version just fine, but the Cyrillic one may as well be from a different planet for all intents and purposes for me, so it doesn’t matter how similar they are. People that can’t read one can’t read one, period.